# Did wives of Nabi (saw) wear niqab?

Tags: hijab, wives-of-the-prophet

Did wives of Nabi salahualaihiwasalam wear niqab?

I found this hadis:

> Narrated Aisha, Ummul Mu'minin:
>
> Riders would pass us when we accompanied the Messenger of Allah (ﷺ)
>   while we were in the sacred state (wearing ihram). When they came by
>   us, one of us would let down her outer garment from her head over her
>   face, and when they had passed on, we would uncover our faces.

http://sunnah.com/abudawud/11/113

Website said hadis is da'if. Is there any sahih hadis?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes the *hadith* from *Sunan Abu Dawud* is daef because of the narrator Yazid bin Abi Ziyad.

There's no authentic *hadith* that proves the Prophets wives covered their faces.

The closest thing what one can use is the ayah from Sural ah-Ahzab 33:53=

> ...And when you ask for anything you want, ask them from behind a
>   screen...

But it can easily be said it's referring to a curtain at home or a door and it doesn't mean covering the face since the ayah is telling the Prophets wives to stay in their homes.

So from this, there's no clear-cut evidence that shows the Prophets wives covered their faces.

Btw, niqab is cultural and not a religious matter.

Answer (score 1):

### Hadith:

> `Aisha used to say: "When (the Verse): "They should draw their veils over their necks and bosoms," was revealed, (the ladies) cut their waist sheets at the edges and covered their faces with the cut pieces."

[Sahih Bukhary](http://sunnah.com/urn/180940)

The complete verse http://quran.com/24/31-31

---

**Updated to answer the the comment:**

The english trnaslation added "cover their faces" because the word خمار (khimar)was used in the Arabic hadith. Ignoring that scholars when explaining this hadith said the word Khimar here refers Niqab(cover the face). Here is a hadith by Aisha saying: Khimar == Niqab.

> *فَخَمَّرْتُ وَجْهِي* بِجِلْبَابِي

[Sahih Muslim](http://sunnah.com/muslim/50/65)

خمرت is the verb of the word (خمار)

وجهي is (my face)

جلبابي is (cloak)

Comment: The Arabic of the hadith doesn't say "covered their faces".  It was added in in English translation.

Comment: @sayyid, answer updated...

Answer (score 0):

Yes they did, When men asked Aishah a question she responded from behind a screen because she wore niqab

O Prophet, tell your *wives* and your daughters and the women of the believers to bring down their khimar over their bosoms" this didn't say and leave the face showing so niqab is fard on them and every muslim women according to ibn abbas, our prophet, and quran